# Angular Material how to get checkbox text-overflow ellipsis

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to get `text-overflow: ellipsis` on the text of a checkbox. How would I do that?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a7tmmp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `width` property to your checkbox. The `text-overflow` property specifies how overflowed content should be displayed. Since the width is not set (even for its parent elements), the text of checkbox keeps extending without overflow.

See this where I added the `width` property to one of the checkbox:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a7tmmp-ix64hc

Comment: Well that was easy

Answer (score 0):

You can also add text-overflow to `.mat-checkbox-layout`, like:

```
.mat-checkbox-layout {
  white-space: no-wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: block;
  width: 200px
}
```

Can wrap this in `::ng-deep {}` to skip encapsulation when you're in a component. For example to target `.mat-checkbox-layout` in your current component and child dom:

```
:host {
  ::ng-deep {
    .mat-checkbox-layout {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```